# Concatenate Input values using useRef and useState [React+typescript]

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am having 2 Inputs and 1 SelectItem, need to concatenate their values so that whenever change occurs in Input or SelectItem, it should be reflected in concatenated string. Here is example code

```
import  Input from '../../components/Input'
const CustomAddressLayout: React.FC<IAddressLayoutProps> = ({ theme, states }) => {
var [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");
const handleChange = (e: any) => {
  inputValue = inputValue +" "+setInputValue(e);
    console.log("target", e);
  }
  return (
    <>
          <Accordion varient={'grouped'} expanded theme={theme}
          items={[
            {
              content:
              <>
              <Input label='Address Line 1' fullWidth={true} type={''} startAdornment={""} endAdornment={""}
                  onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)} id={''} theme={theme} dynamic={false} />
              <Input label='Address Line 2' fullWidth={true} type={''} startAdornment={""} endAdornment={""}
                  onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)} id={''} theme={theme} dynamic={false} />
              <Select label='State' theme={theme} items={states} sxProps={{ m: 2, width: 100 }}
                  onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}></Select>
              </>,
              isExpanded: true,
              key: "string",
              subtitle: inputValue, ////// HERE concatenated value should be updated where as ///////////////////////////////////////////////it replaces previous input value
              title: "Mailing Address",
              actionBtn: <></>
            }
           ]}
          />   
       
    </>
  )
}
export default CustomAddressLayout
```

I am newbie to React.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to use the variable `inputValue` to manage three different values. You could try adding more state variables, one for each form field.

```
const [addressL1, setAddressL1] = useState('');
const [addressL2, setAddressL2] = useState('');
const [stateCode, setStateCode] = useState('');
```

Then, simplify the onChange prop for each field to something like...

```
 <Input label='Address Line 1' onChange={(e) => setAddressL1(e)} .../>
```

Finally, concat the values. String interpolation is good for this if you want to control the formatting between each variable. It also makes it easy to read the value of subtitle.

```
subtitle: `${addressL1} ${addressL2} ${stateCode}`
```

Keep in mind that concatenating these values with the same variable and handle function could result in the data being placed out of order (state + AddL2 + AddL1), depending on how a user interacts with the fields.

Comment: it worked like charm, hats off buddy